# StarUML doesn't open my .uml file

Tags: uml, staruml

I'm trying to open an `.uml` file I received from someone else, but StarUML just won't open it. On the Internet says that I must open it from the explorer, but what if my file is not in the explorer? I've tried in different ways and I just can't.

Answer (score 8):

I was googling the internet trying to do the exact same thing when I think I solved it (for myself at least).

Go to File > Import > StarUML 1 File (.uml) ...

And then select your file.

It will appear at the bottom in "Diagram thumbnails" and then if you double click it, then it should open in model explorer. Hope this helps!